# scroll the view simultaneously as the scrollView scrolls

Tags: android, scrollview, react-native, sticky

```
scrollPositionX: new Animated.Value(0),    

scrollEventThrottle={16}
onScroll={Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: this.state.scrollPositionX}}}] )}

<Animated.View style={[styles.times, {
     transform: [{translateX: this.state.scrollPositionX}]
}]}>
   ...
</Animated.View>
```

---

This code works but it scrolls the animated view in opposite direction. How do i make it scroll in the same direction.
this is with respect to the issue -
[React Native ScrollView Sticky View Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230676/react-native-scrollview-sticky-view-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`interpolate`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#interpolate):

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.times, {
  transform: [{
    translateX: this.state.scrollPositionX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1], 
      outputRange: [0, -1]
    })
  }]
}]}>
```